# JQuery to get value from bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is my html code which came through handlebars

```html
<div class="form-group" id="lab-domain-body">
  <label or="scheduleConfigurationFieldDropdown">Select Configuration</label>
  <div class="dropdown  form-control--transparent">
    <input type="TextBox" value id="configuration" class="schedule-configuration sr-only" readonly required/>
    <button class="btn btn__dropdown dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="scheduleConfigurationFieldDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="test1">v1.3</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu modal-body__schedule-ul" id="demolist" aria-labelledby="scheduleConfigurationFieldDropdown">
      <li><span> v1.3</span></li>
      <li><span>MDSO</span></li>
      <li><span>v1.6</span></li>
      <li><span>v11.8</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want as soon user selects  item just need to get value from dropdown menu.
Following is a Jquery which i tried till now, tried everything but nothing seems to work in my case.

1. ```
   //This function is never get called  

   $('#demolist li a').on('click', function(){
       $('#configuration').val($(this).text());
   });
   ```
2. I tried enable submit button which is working fine. But still not able to get value from dropdown menu. I didn't think it should be hard enough but stuck. Tried every method on stackoverflows.

   ```
   $form.on('change input', 'input', enableSubmit);

     function enableSubmit(xyz) {
      console.log(($('.schedule-configuration')).val());
      var bc = $('#configuration').val($(this).text());
       var xyz = ($('.schedule-configuration')).text();
       console.log(xyz[0]);

     // Jquery to get value from selected 
     $formSubmit.prop('disabled', false);
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: where is that `a` selector came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#demolist li', function() {
  $('#configuration').val($(this).children('span').text());
});
```

And a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/xj5oponw/

Comment: Please see my updated question again i tried your method but it gives me array rather than a value

Comment: The fiddle is adjusted. The text value is shown with an alert and in the console.

Comment: No i see fiddle is same .

Comment: Is it same fiddle

Comment: No its not showing any update to me after your update also

Comment: I had to create a new one. It doesn't seem to update. https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/yedp3ppf/

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching the click event handler to `$('#demolist li a')`, but there's no `<a>` element in your `<ul>`. Try attaching the event handler to `$('#demolist li span')`.

EDIT:

You need to wrap the attached event in a $(document).ready() function.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc4rpyt8/8/

And here's the code you need:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#demolist li span').on('click', function(){
        $('#configuration').val($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: changing this function to       $('#demolist li span').on('click', function(){
    $('#configuration').val($(this).text());
}); .. as soon as i select option but function is not called.

Comment: Sorry Dragos .. this function is not getting called.